# Dump database with date added in filename

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Hi i have created this to try to dump a database with date added to the filename. But it fails apparently i cannot execute the @dumptorun correctly.

```
 declare @pvm varchar(30), @dumptorun varchar(300), @dbname varchar(70)
 select @pvm=(CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 112))
 select @dbname='master'
 select @dumptorun = 'dump database '+@dbname+' to d:\temp\'+@dbname+'_'+@pvm+'.dmp go'
 select @dumptorun
EXEC ( @dumptorun )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the "go" after the dump database command